# JavaScript/node - array of functions as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I looked thru other questions like this and I think I'm doing what the answers say. Still I'm getting a node TypeError with the following:

```
const ALL_ITEM_CLASSES = [
    require( './equipment/torsoe/LightTorsoe.js' ),
    require( './equipment/torsoe/MedTorsoe.js' ),
    require( './equipment/torsoe/HeavyTorsoe.js' ),
    require( './equipment/boots/LightBoots.js' ),
    require( './equipment/boots/MedBoots.js' ),
    require( './equipment/boots/HeavyBoots.js' )
];

var ItemGenerator = {
    getRandomItem: function( classArray, minQuality, maxQuality ) {
        if( !classArray ) {
            classArray = ALL_ITEM_CLASSES;
        }

        var ItemClass = classArray[ Math.floor(Math.random()*classArray.length) ]; 

        return ItemClass( minQuality + Math.random()*(maxQuality-minQuality) ); // TypeError: ItemClass is not a function
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var boots = ItemGenerator.getRandomItem( [LightBoots,MedBoots,HeavyBoots], 0, 1.0 )
```

Anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks...

p.s. per @Pointy 's comment, here's an example of one of the classes (the rest are all of the same boilerplate):

```
var LightBoots = function( quality ) {
    return {
        slot: "boots",
        type: "light",
        quality: quality,
        armorClass: Math.round( 2+quality*3.5 ),
        magicalGravity: quality
    };
}
module.exports = LightBoots;
```

Comment: Well it all depends on exactly what those various files are actually exporting. Modules can export anything. Post the code for one of those and perhaps the problem will be made evident.

Comment: Try to get more info on where it fails. For example, move the `Math.floor(Math.random()*classArray.length)` thing into a separate variable, and then `console.log` both the random index and the class returned by classArray for that index. My guess is that some class you're providing maybe undefined.

Comment: And they're all like that? You can add a `console.log(ItemClass)` line to your `getRandomItem()` function to check what the variable actually contains. Oh, and when you call the function, you're passing in another array; where do those values come from?

Comment: Does it work if you call `getRandomItem` without passing an array?

Comment: sorry guys, should have clarified - the TypeError is from the node parser. it doesn't even get to execution

Comment: ... no problem if i just go `var ItemClass = ALL_ITEM_CLASSES[ Math.floor(Math.random()*classArray.length) ];`

Comment: @RobertLombardo the parameter you pass in is `[LightBoots,MedBoots,HeavyBoots]`.  If those three symbols have not been defined (and note that those `require()` calls **will not** define them, then the values in that array will be `undefined`. (And the TypeError is definitely from execution, not parsing.)